# MySQL & Vapor 3: unrecognized basic packet, full auth not supported

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent, fluent-mysql

I want to connect a MySQL database on my machine with a Vapor 3 app.
My current `configure.swift` file looks as follows:

```
try services.register(FluentMySQLProvider())

...

let mysqlConfig = MySQLDatabaseConfig(
    username: "dev",
    password: "",
    database: "test"
)
let mysql = MySQLDatabase(config: mysqlConfig)

var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: mysql, as: .mysql)
services.register(databases)
```

This works just fine. However, since I need to add my Model to the migration configuration, I also need to add:

```
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Posts.self, database: .mysql)
services.register(migrations)
```

When running the app this time, I'm seeing an error saying:

> Full authentication not supported over insecure connections.

After some research, it seems that this error can be overcome by changing the password logic from `caching_sha2_password` to `mysql_native_password`.
However, that leaves me with the error saying:

> Unrecognized basic packet.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From MySQL 8 if you want to use it on `localhost` (unsecured connection) then you need to disable the MySQL transport layer security. Use `unverifiedTLS` for `transport` in `MySQLDatabaseConfig` initializer.

Your `MySQLDatabaseConfig` initializer should look something like this:

```
let config = MySQLDatabaseConfig(
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 3306,
    username: "dev",
    password: "",
    database: "test",
    transport: MySQLTransportConfig.unverifiedTLS
)
```

It should work fine with this configuration.

Comment: Thanks again for this!